# Merge a png on top of a gif with shell

Tags: shell, terminal, conversion, png, gif

I am trying to merge a png with a gif (put the png on top of the gif) and then have the result as a gif.

I played around with `convert`, but cannot quite get it to work the way I need it.

I have tried these commands so far:

```
convert layer1.png layer2.gif -append mergedLayers.gif
convert-im6.q16: memory allocation failed `layer2.gif' @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1303.
```

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: what are the contents of `identify -list policy | more` . it should return a policy file, please add it's contents in your initial answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `ffmpeg`:

`ffmpeg -y -i layer2.gif -i layer1.png -filter_complex [0]overlay=x=0:y=0[out] -map [out] -map 0:a? mergedLayers.gif`

`-y` flag says to overwrite output files without asking. So if you already have a file named `mergedLayers.gif` it will get overwritten when this command is run.

`-i` flag is the input url (in this case just a file name). So you are passing two input files. `layer2.gif` and `layer1.png`.

`-filter_complex` flag in a sense is the function that is done on the inputs to make the output. In this case the function is `[0]overlay=x=0:y=0[out]`. The `[0]` indicates that you want to use the first input file as the object that is being overlayed on. If you were to use `[1]` instead of `[0]` you would end up with the png as the bottom layer. `overlay=x=0:y=0` tells where to place the overlayed object. You can adjust where the png appears on the image by changing the x and y values in `[0]overlay=x=0:y=0[out]`. `x=0:y=0` is the top left of the image. Increasing the value for x will move the image to the right. Increasing the value for y will move the image down. If `=x=0:y=0` is omitted, `overlay` defaults to `x=0:y=0`.

`-map` flag is a way to designate an input as a source for the output. Probably unnecessary in such a simple case and you could just do:

`ffmpeg -y -i layer2.gif -i layer1.png -filter_complex [0]overlay=x=0:y=0 mergedLayers.gif`